# Which editors can autocomplete any word from document?

Tags: editors, auto-completion

Of course, any LaTeX editor will autocomplete common LaTeX commands and environments. Many (most?) let user add new commands to be autocompleted. However, in technical documents there will usually be specific terms, which are encountered often enough (and may be quite long) to be worth autocompleting, but aren't commands and are different from one document to another. So it's quite nice to be able to autocomplete any word which exists in the document (or any of the open documents).

I know Emacs, Vim, Kile and TeXstudio support this; do any others?

Comment: So these "specific terms" are not commands themselves, as in `\blahblah...`? I know that's a very technical command. `:-|`

Comment: Textmate (macromates.com) does that.

Comment: @Werner: Yes. E.g. you are writing an article on synchrocyclotrons or something, and don't want to write the word "synchrocyclotron" out each time.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov: Did you know that it is possible to define a command (say) `\sync` that expands "`What mighty \sync you have, sir!`" to "`What mighty synchrocyclotrons you have, sir!`". *Any* LaTeX editor can do this, but it is restricted to control sequences/commands (prepended with `\`, in the general sense).

Comment: @Werner: Yes, of course, that's an option.

Comment: Is this question specific to Linux? If so please add to the title and tag it accordingly. Otherwise, editors like WinEdt and Texniccenter also are able to support this via macros. But searching every word in the dictionary is annoying at the least unless it waits until you enter 3 letters then the search begins or something similar. Led used to do this before they abandoned the project (AFAIK). At first it was quite impressive but then you start looking for options to turn it off.

Comment: @percusse: No, it's definitely not specific to Linux. I quite agree it can be annoyed when done wrong.

Comment: TeXnicCenter supports it without macros as far as I remember. And you had settings to tell it to only start looking after having entered x letters. I foind it horrible though, don't use it in kile at the moment either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Any* LaTeX editor can accommodate this style of auto-completion by means of macro definitions. It is probably the fastest way to perform this without having to switch from your existing editor to a new/different one. In my opinion, it is flexible, transferable and accommodates a host of variability that you may require based on (say) conditional support from LaTeX packages.

Since the replacement text is typically used inside regular text, the [`xspace` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xspace) is of great help. It inserts a space after a command sequence only if it is followed by a space. This is a common issue with using command sequences in regular text. For example, `A \TeX command sequence.` will expand to `A TeXcommand sequence.` since the space represents the end of `\TeX` and is therefore gobbled. `xspace` is the way around this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xspace
% Definitions for words to auto-complete
\newcommand{\sync}{synchrocyclotrons\xspace}%
%...
\begin{document}
What mighty \sync you have, sir! Get me one of those \sync.
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you change your mind (to quote ABBA), you can just change the macro definition. It would probably be the same amount of effort to do this than it would to modify the auto-completion segment provided by such an editor.

To go one step further, you can even define your macros to have (say) starred version `*` which expand to the plural form if use, otherwise it uses the singular form:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xprase
\usepackage{xspace}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xspace
% Definitions for words to auto-complete
\NewDocumentCommand{\sync}{s}{%
  synchrocyclotron\IfBooleanTF{#1}{s}{}\xspace
}
%...
\begin{document}
That's a huge \sync! There are plenty more \sync* over there.
\end{document}
```

[image]

The [`xparse` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) provides an easy interface for working with starred versions of commands/environments.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to `AucTeX` commands of insertion/completion for macros or environments, `emacs` provides a specific method to expand any word in any buffer and in any mode: the command `dabbrev-expand` (M-/).

> `dabbrev-expand` expands to the most recent, preceding word for which this is a prefix. If no suitable preceding word is found, words following point are
>   considered.  If still no suitable word is found, then look in the
>   buffers accepted by the function pointed out by variable
>   `dabbrev-friend-buffer-function`.
>
> A positive prefix argument, N, says to take the Nth backward *distinct*
>   possibility.  A negative argument says search forward.
>
> If the cursor has not moved from the end of the previous expansion and
>   no argument is given, replace the previously-made expansion
>   with the next possible expansion not yet tried.

*(The latter feature is very handy...)*

Answer (score 2):

Kile has autocompletion for all words in the document. [This is the documentation for that feature](http://kile.sourceforge.net/Documentation/html/complete_auto.html).

Comment: The OP has already mentioned Kile :)

Answer (score 2):

TeXworks has some builtin autocompletion, but take a look at the script [autocompleteForTexworks](https://raw.github.com/henrikmidtiby/autocompleteForTexworks/master/scripts/autocomplete.js). The script can perform completion on long words earlier used in your document, labels and filenames for `\input`, `\include` and `\includegraphics` macros.
In addition it can also close earlier opened environments.

There is a video of it in action on [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gRSq_OSxPec).

Guide to use.

1. start typing the long word that should be autocompleted
2. press "crtl + m" and the autocompleter will complete the word or at least make a suggestion for a completion.
3. if not satisfied with the suggestion press "crtl + m" until the correct word is found.

Disclaimer: I'm author of the autocomplete script.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows - TeXStudio (earlier TeXmakerX) has these facilities. The down side is everytime you time some environment or command it shows the complete help for it!

Answer (score 1):

Use vim with the Supertab plugin. So you can type in the first letters of your long word and than type TAB.

Comment: Or ctrl-N and Ctrl-P without any plugin.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) has that capability. You will find instructions on how to set up Notepad++ as an LaTeX IDE [in this StackExchange message](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43984/9632).

Answer (score 1):

For Mac OS X, [BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/index.html) includes words from the current document as autocompletion candidates.

Answer (score 1):

Texmaker is the best typesetting editor which I've worked with. It has versions for Linux, Windows & Mac.

I used it in Windows which has many auto-completion commands, and provides a dictionary for many languages.

Answer (score 1):

For [WinEdt](http://www.winedt.com) (Windows) there are two macros for auto-completion on [WinEdt's community site](http://www.winedt.org):

- [complete](http://www.winedt.org/Macros/text/complete.php) will incrementally search backwards for words starting with the same letters as the current word; you can invoke the macro multiple times until you get the word you are looking for;
- [completeWord](http://www.winedt.org/Macros/text/completeWord.php) will instead present you a list of possible completions to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

Under Linux I recommend "Kate".
It's simple, fast & pretty amazing!

An other alternative for Linux that wasn't mentioned above, is Geany with GeanyLaTeX Plugin.

On Windows Notepad++ is the most brilliant solution. But TexStudio is also not bad...