# Editor with Word like "word completion" feature

Tags: editors, auto-completion

Besides defining longer technical words by

```
\newcommand{\trimam}{trans-impedance-amplifier}
```

to save typing time.

Is there a Latex Editor (can be Linux or Windows) that offers "word completion"

https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Word_Completion_for_Text_Documents

similar like Libreoffice or Word. For technical documents \newcommand might be better changing a technical term afterwards through the whole document. But for prose text I would prefer a "word completion" feature indexing already used words and offering shortcut completion when typing first three letters.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: See [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339) for a long list.  I would assume that most editors support word completion.  Emacs/AUCTeX definitely does.

Comment: Kile does this.

Comment: While I don't recommend it, there is nothing that prevents you from using Word to create your LaTeX source files, if you save them in text mode.  Then, you just need a separate window through which to invoke LaTeX upon your newly-created Word text document.  I'm not being facetious ... I use such an approach, sans Word as the editor.

Comment: vim with SuperTab-plugin does. There is a plugin for everything, even thesaurus.

Comment: @alexurba thx for the link, I asked the question as I found myself many latex editors offering code completion, command index and shortcut or closing brackets, but no word completion

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31718/7674

Comment: And of course, in the same feuding boat as Vim, Emacs has this feature (out of the box, I believe).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Windows, [WinEdt](http://winedt.com) offers this feature. You write few letters of a word and then press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>Enter</kbd>. A pop-up window will show you the possible list of words as in the following figure.

[image]

Double clicking on the desired word will insert it in the place.

---

**Sublimetext**

Sublime text too has this feature. But I found that its word completion is not as thorough as WinEdt. For example it didn't know the completion for the word `assume` as I did in winedt. But, may be we have to do something extra to have all words, which I never explored. Here you have to press few letters of the word and then press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>Space</kbd> to view the options as in the figure. Then click on the desired word to get it in place.

PS. Pressing  <kbd>Tab</kbd> will insert the first word in the above list i.e, `hamburgers`.

[image]

---

**Texmaker**

In texmaker, `right click` on the half completed word, a pop-up window will open with possible suggestions. Click on the desired word to insert it. Same works in TeXstudio also.

[image]

---

**TeXnicCenter**

Though I could not get it work (as I am not good in using TeXnicCenter), there is an option for completing words.

[image]

Those who know, please feel free to edit and add details.

---

**gedit**

[gedit](https://projects.gnome.org/gedit/) with the "word completion" plugin activated, it shows a dynamic list of possible matches.

---

Comment: thanks for the nice overview. One correction, it seems TexnicCenter (I use this one currently) has only code completion, but no word completion, so only "/word/" gets completed

Comment: I am using texstudio which is excellent but I could not find this feature. Would you help me to activate this feature?

Comment: @prashanta_himalay Texstudio is similar to texmaker. Right click on the incomplete word.

Comment: @HarishKumar True. But I was not getting the same thing in my Ubuntu version. But checked with other Linux and it is working fine.

Answer (score 6):

Emacs can also do this, for example using Toby Cubitt's predictive mode. There are a bunch of other modes that can also help, as well.

[image]

Other options include [AutoComplete](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoComplete) and [company-mode](http://company-mode.github.io/)

Even more options are listed in the [Emacswiki Completion Category page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryCompletion#toc2)

Answer (score 1):

**TeXWorks** also have the ability to complete the words included in a word list file, which is located in `~/.TeXworks/completion/` as a simple file text (like `word_list.txt`).

And as said before, **Kile** does it to, with a `word_list.cwl` located in `~/.kde/share/apps/kile/complete/dictionary/` (then go to the settings to add this file to auto-completion).

Answer (score 0):

In [February 2013](https://www.sharelatex.com/blog/2013/02/04/introducing-auto-complete.html#.Un031PlwqSo), the online editor [ShareLaTeX](http://www.sharelatex.com) introduced auto-completion for already-used commands within your document:

[image]

Future improvements may include scanning packages that are loaded to add to the available auto-completion selection.