# Word prediction when typing LaTeX

Tags: auto-completion

Some time ago I while preparing my Bachelor's thesis I came across a word prediction macro for Microsoft Word - the preDict:

- http://www.beingbrunel.com/predictive-text-in-word/
- https://github.com/thomasmichaelwallace/preDict

I found it quite useful when one has to type longer texts with many but often repeating terms specific to a concrete area.

In the meantime I began using LaTeX for producing scientific texts and sometimes miss such functionality.

Today I looked at some alternatives and came across [Presage](http://presage.sourceforge.net/?q=node/3). It can be used with a "front-end", such as pyprompter and gprompter:

- https://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/05/gprompter-text-editor-with-word-prediction/
- https://github.com/Manouchehri/presage/tree/master/apps/gtk/gprompter
- https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gprompter/

These are both very basic and I think that integrating some word prediction back-end, such as Presage, with a modern (TeX) editor would be very convenient and useful.

At a first glance, I remember that Atom is quite extensible and supports LaTeX. I use TeXStudio personally, but do not think that it could predict the word that is intended to be typed next. I had tried to leverage the autocomplete feature for this task a while ago, but I did not succeed.

Has anybody tried to integrate the word prediction feature into any LaTeX editor?
Which editors would be possible candidates for adding this features?
Are there any other well-suited word prediction back-ends which I am missing?

Some of these questions seem to be answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128377/editor-with-word-like-word-completion-feature) so I hope this is not a duplicate.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is a well-researched question, but I'm afraid I don't anticipate any better results compared to treating this as a duplicate of the other question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128377/editor-with-word-like-word-completion-feature).